# Hide content box with Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types

Ive created a custom post type and I want to hide the main textarea content in the publish/edit page.

Is it possible ?

Thanks!

Comment: Working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68749925/7186739

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, remove the editor support from your custom post type.

You can do it in two ways.

1. While registering your custom post type:

Example:

```
$args = array(
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'supports' => array('title','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments')
); 
register_post_type('book',$args);
```

2.Using the remove_post_type support if the custom post type is not defined by your code (i.e some other plugin/theme has defined custom post type).

Example:

```
add_action('init', 'my_rem_editor_from_post_type');
function my_rem_editor_from_post_type() {
    remove_post_type_support( <POST TYPE>, 'editor' );
}
```

Comment: You can upload files using the media manager, or build your own custom meta box to handle the uploads.

Answer (score 14):

When registering your custom post type don't specify support for editor.

```
 $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    // on the supports param here you see no 'editor'
    'supports' => array('title','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments') 
  ); 
  register_post_type('book',$args);
```

More information See: [Function Reference/register post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Example).

Answer (score 4):

You can also set

```
'supports' => false
```

to avoid default (title and editor) behavior.

Note: this is for 3.5 or greater.

Comment: Ok, how you can generate and save/manage the content then?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove tittle or editor in admin of post module

```
function mvandemar_remove_post_type_support() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'title' );
    remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'editor' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'mvandemar_remove_post_type_support' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set `editor` `false`

```
$supports = array(
    'title', // post title
    'editor'=> false, // post content
    'author', // post author
    'thumbnail', // featured images
    'excerpt', // post excerpt
    'custom-fields', // custom fields
    'comments', // post comments
    'revisions', // post revisions
    'post-formats', // post formats
);
```

I hope this helps you